# Error while using JADE and mongoose objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug

I'm having problems while rendering a jade template where I'd like to pass an array variable with objects that contains ObjectId (fmor Mongo)

```
{ name: 'fake',
  slug: 'FAKE',
  address: 'fake',
  city: 'Madrid',
  country: 'Spain',
  _owner: 51f65388f98a405469000003,
  _id: 51f65389f98a405469000007}
```

This is the representation when doing #{objects}.

This, obviously, leads to an TOKEN ILLEGAL... How can I insert this variables into jade without breaking anything.

Comment: I tried to recreate this on my machine and I'm also getting ObjectIds not in quotes when doing console.log of the object that I'm passing to jade and it works fine. Can you show some of your jade code? And perhaps let us know what version of jade you are using?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is due to the missing quotes, you should convert _owner and _id to strings before passing to the template.

```
{ 
  name: 'fake',
  slug: 'FAKE',
  address: 'fake',
  city: 'Madrid',
  country: 'Spain',
  _owner: '51f65388f98a405469000003', // convert to string
  _id: '51f65389f98a405469000007'     // convert to string
}
```

In mongoose, you can do

```
obj._owner.toHexString();
obj._id.toHexString();
```